# WSO2 Identity Server (5.7.0) External Encryption of Secondary Userstore Connection Password

Tags: ldap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using the cipher encryption method for my passwords in the WSO2 Identity Server. I am able to create a connection in this way to my primary user store, but when I try to create a connection to my secondary user store I get this message:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-01-30 20:44:10,356] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tracker.UserStoreManagerRegistry} -  Adding UserStoreManager with name: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager. UserStoreManager class: org.w
so2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager@1b128113
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-01-30 20:44:10,361] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.UserStoreConfigXMLProcessor} -  External password management is disabled.
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-01-30 20:44:10,361] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} -  Start initializing class with the first option
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-01-30 20:44:10,361] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Initialization Started 1548881050361
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-01-30 20:44:10,361] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Checking LDAP configurations
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-01-30 20:44:10,361] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  ReadGroups is enabled for [SECONDARY-USERSTORE] 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-01-30 20:44:10,362] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext} -  Connection Name :: [Connection Name], Connection URL :: [Connection Url]
TID: [-1] [] [2019-01-30 20:44:10,451] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler} -  LOAD IMMEDIATE started
TID: [-1] [] [2019-01-30 20:44:10,452] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler} -  Started loading 3000 jobs from db
TID: [-1] [] [2019-01-30 20:44:10,453] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler} -  Beginning a new transaction
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-01-30 20:44:10,538] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext} -  Error obtaining connection. [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
```

I don't know why this is happening in my secondary userstore but not my primary user store. I have the same setup, using the cipher-tool.properties file with configuration:

```
UserStore.[UserStoreName].Property.ConnectionPassword=repository/deployment/server/userstores/[UserStoreName].xml//UserStoreManager/Property[@name='ConnectionPassword'],false
```

In my cipher-text.properties file:

```
UserStore.[UserStoreName].Property.ConnectionPassword=[LdapPassword]
```

If I remove the connection to the cipher configurations and place the password straight in the file, I am able to make the connection no problem.
Why doesn't this configuration work?